# Recall Vs. remember

Tags: word-in-context

In this context **recall** and **remember** would be the same?

> "I **recall** myself when I was 5 years old in my family house, it
>   was an amazing time for me".
>
> "I **remember** myself when I was 5 years old in my family house, it
>   was an amazing time for me".

Comment: See [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/154337/what's-the-difference-between-recall-and-remember) related question.

Comment: FWIW, in either case, I'd omit *myself*. Neither of these words requires the reflexive pronoun.

Answer (score 1):

I think the two phrases should probably be:

> "I recall that when I was 5 years old in my family house, it was an amazing time for me".

And

> "I remember when I was 5 years old in my family house, it was an amazing time for me".

Neither requires "myself", but it's usable for the "remember" one. The more common one would be "I remember when..."